# Performance of User Defined Functions in SQL Server 2000 and 2005

Tags: performance, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2000, user-defined-functions

We have two tables, `Customer` and `CustomerEvent` both contains few million rows. On SQL Server 2000, we deployed an UDF called `fn_CustomerEvent` which returns `TRUE` or `FALSE` based on two parameters `CustomerID` and `EventCode`, e.g.

```
SELECT dbo.fn_CustomerEvent(1345678, 'Music')
```

The UDF code is:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_CustomerEvent](@CustomerID INT, @EviCode NVARCHAR(10))
RETURNS NVARCHAR(10)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @List NVARCHAR(10)

    SELECT @List = CASE 
                     WHEN COUNT(*) > 0 THEN 'TRUE'
                     ELSE 'FALSE'
                   END 
    FROM CustomerEvent
    WHERE   
         CustomerID = @CustomerID 
         AND EviCode = @EviCode

    RETURN @List
END
```

The performance on SQL Server 2000 was great. Return TOP 5000 rows within 3 seconds. For example,

```
SELECT TOP 5000 
     CustomerID, dbo.fn_CustomerEvent(1345678, 'Music')
FROM [Table1]
```

But now, we are moving to SQL Server 2005. Same code, same UDF, but performance drops dramatically from 3 seconds to 1 minutes 20 seconds.

Can anyone point me a right direction on where should I start to optimize the performance?

Answer (score 3):

The scalar UDF is evaluated for each row (i.e. 5000 times). You could either call it once and store the result in a variable

```
DECLARE @Result nvarchar(10)
SELECT @Result = dbo.fn_CustomerEvent(1345678, 'Music') 

SELECT TOP 5000 
     CustomerID, @Result
FROM [Table1]
```

or you can use an inline TVF (and I would also use `EXISTS` instead of `COUNT`)

```
CREATE FUNCTION CustomerEvent (@CustomerID INT, 
                               @EviCode    NVARCHAR(10)) 
RETURNS TABLE 
AS 
  RETURN 
    (SELECT CASE 
              WHEN EXISTS(SELECT * 
                          FROM   CustomerEvent 
                          WHERE  CustomerID = @CustomerID 
                                 AND EviCode = @EviCode) THEN 'TRUE' 
              ELSE 'FALSE' 
            END)
```

See [Scalar functions, inlining, and performance: An entertaining title for a boring post](http://dataeducation.com/scalar-functions-inlining-and-performance-an-entertaining-title-for-a-boring-post/) for more about this technique.

Answer (score 1):

There is one big problem with UDF's: they don't work with indexes. If you want to get code re-use and maintain performance, I will normally build either a computed column (which can be indexed) or a view.

Comment: Not sure what you mean "they don't work with indexes" can you elaborate? The execution plan for a UDF can use an index.

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE FUNCTION CustomerEvent (@CustomerID INT, 
                               @EviCode    NVARCHAR(10)) 
RETURNS TABLE 
AS 
  RETURN 
    (SELECT COALESCE((SELECT 'TRUE' FROM CustomerEvent
                    WHERE   
                         CustomerID = @CustomerID 
                         AND EviCode = @EviCode)
                , 'FALSE'))
```

Check for Indexes, Rebuild Them and Update your statistics.

Comment: This will throw an error if more than one row matches the `WHERE`